# Сформировать ответ в AJAX в соответственном формате

Tags: php, ajax

Ребята ,помогите пожалуйста сформировать правильный ответ в аяксе.
Есть скрипт который собственно и формирует этот ответ .

```
    <?php
// паметры подключения
$serverName = "localhost, 1433"; 
$uid = "web_user";   
$pwd = "Gf45Rn27G";  
$databaseName = "plc_server"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd,"Database"=>$databaseName); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

// переменнные для запроса
$page  = 1;
$group = 1;
$answer = '[';

if ($conn){
    //echo "Подключение к серверу успешно!<br/>";
    // обработка запроса  
    $tsql = "SELECT SVG_NAME,PARAMETERS,TYPE_PARAMETERS FROM SVG_PARAMETERS  WHERE SVG_PAGE='$page' and SVG_GROUP='$group' and ENABLE='1' ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 

    if( $stmt === false )  
        {  
            echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";  
        }  

    if($stmt  === false)  
        {  
            echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";  
        } 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  echo "SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."--->>>".$row[1]."--->>>".$row[2]."</br>";  
}
}else{
    echo "Нет подключения к серверу. <br/>";
}
$answer = $answer.'{"obj":"end","type":"0"}]';
echo $answer ;
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);  
sqlsrv_close( $conn); 
?>
```

**Он выдает такой ответ :**

```
SVG_NAME: NVD_10--->>>"color":"fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;","blnk":"none"--->>>1
```

[{"obj":"end","type":"0"}]

***и формат этого этого ответа не правильный .***

**Нужно что-то типа такого:**

```
[{"obj":"NVD_10","type":"1","color":"fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;","blnk":"none"},{"obj":"end","type":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сконкатенировали требуемые данные к своей строке.

```
answer .= '{"obj":"SVG_NAME: ".$row[0]."--->>>".$row[1]."--->>>".$row[2]."</br>"},';


$answer .= $answer.'{"obj":"end","type":"0"}]';
```

попробуйте заменить вот эти строки тем что я указал должно получится требуемое.

А почему не используете json? мне кажется в вашей ситуации было бы логичнее собрать массив и вернуть ответ при помощи json_encode();

Comment: Я уже решил задачу но спасибо все равно за ответ )